# Data conversion from document to relational database

Tags: database-design, relational-database, relationship, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert some law texts into relational tables. I've exhausted all online resources that's why I decided to ask this question for I'm clueless about what to do next.

I have a sentence that's saved to db that follows this structure:

Title -> Chapter -> Article -> Section -> Subsection -> Sentence

The problem is that a sentence can be anywhere & any item in the structure doesn't have to have a parent:

```
Ex1:
Title 1
   sentence 1
   sentence 2
   sentence 3
   Chapter 1
       sentence 4
   Chapter 2
       Article 1
           sentence 5
           Section 1
               Subsection 1
                   sentence 6

Ex2:
Article 1
   sentence 7
   sentence 8
   Section 1
       sentence 9
       sentence 10
```

Comment: How this follow this _Title -> Chapter -> Article -> Section -> Subsection -> Sentence_ structure?

Comment: for instance, a sentence can have a title & be placed directly into it or it can have no title but a chapter and a subsection. they're basically used to identify law texts and by design they're made like that.

Comment: Then create your tables with a column let's call it `sentence INT NULL` reference the `Sentences` table.

Comment: what if multiple sentences have the same title or the same chapter ?

Comment: It depends on your needs there, if so create a column in the `Sentences` table, and if it's a many to many relationship you will need another table for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presented case is a good example when document-oriented data model fits better that relational one. However, you always can map any hierarchical database schema to relational one. For example.

```
item_types
----------
id  name
--- ----------
1   Title
2   Chapter
3   Article
4   Section
5   Subsection
6   Sentence

textes
------
id  name
--- -----------
1   Test text 1
2   Test text 2

text_structure (Key: text_id + item_index)
--------------
text_id  item_index parent_index item_type content
-------  ---------- ------------ --------- ------------
1        1          NULL         1         Title 1
1        2          1            6         sentence 1
1        3          1            6         sentence 2
1        4          1            6         sentence 3
1        5          1            2         Chapter 1
1        6          5            6         sentence 4
...
2        1          NULL         3         Article 1
2        2          1            6         sentence 7
2        3          1            6         sentence 8
2        4          1            4         Section 1
2        5          4            6         sentence 9
2        6          4            6         sentence 10
```